# Proof for $a\cdot b \neq a$ in a field with four elements $\{0,1,a,b\}$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, abelian-groups

Is there a formal (but not advanced-level, I'm still a beginner) proof for $a\cdot b \neq a$ in a Field? (Körper in German).

I looked at lots of resources, but could only find for $0a = a0 = 0$, the commutative, associative laws, and a couple of others.

The field given is with 4 distinct elements $0, 1, a, b$. The hint on my question paper says to prove by contradiction (Widerspruch).

Any pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: If $ab=a$, then $b=1$, since by hypothesis $a\neq 0$, but $b=1$ is a contradiction because $b\neq 1$.

Comment: Xammm how do you know ab=a implies b=1? That needs to be proven. It's not a given property of fields. But it *can* be proven. But it must be proven before it can be used.

Comment: Since it is a Field, there exists a multiplicative inverse for $a$ that can be applied to both sides of the equation.

Comment: If ab=a then b=1b=a'ab=a'a=1 which is a contradiction.

Comment: Anyone know why I'm getting downvotes? If the down-voter can leave the reason, that'd be great and I can avoid such mistakes in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is only true if $b \neq 1$ and $a \neq 0$. If $b = 1$, certainly $a\cdot b = a\cdot 1 = a$. If $a \neq 0$, then $a\cdot b = 0 = a$.

Now to prove it, 
Assume $a\cdot b = a$,  $b \neq 1$ and $a \neq 0$. But $1$ is the distinct element of the field such that $x \cdot 1 = x$ for any $x$ in the field. Then $ b = 1$. Contradiction.

Comment: It is only true of $b\ne 1$ _and_ $a\ne 0$ ... and since you're missing the second of these conditions, there must be something wrong with your proof.

Comment: Ah yes, I agree. I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! +1

Comment: It's not part of the definition of field that 1 is a distinct element where for *some* non-zero a we have ab=a.  You have to prove such a statement.  That another b != 1 might exist (for a, not nescessarily all other elements) is in no way a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the definition of a field is that for every $a \ne 0$ there exist a $a^{-1} $ so that $a^{-1}a=1$.

So if $ab=a $ then either

i) $a =0$ and $ab=0b=0=a $

or

ii) $a\ne 0$ and therefore:

$ab=a $

$a^{-1}ab=a^{-1}a $

$1*b=1$

$b=1$.

So if you are given $ab=a $ in a field you can always conclude either $b=1$ or $a=0$.

Comment: If you need a contradiction, we can rule out i) from the start ii) concludes b=1 which is a contradiction of what you were given.